# 二次元配列の要素を一つずつ読み込んで処理をしたい

Tags: python

二次元配列Bの要素を一つずつ読み込んで以下の処理を行いたいです。
書き方が分からない行は疑問点１、疑問点２としてコメントアウトしてあります。

```py
A = [['apple', 1],['banana', 2],['orange', 3],['grape', 4]]
B = [['apple', 'ringo'],['banana', 'banana'],['orange', 'orenji'],['grape', 'budou']]

#(疑問点１)Bの０番目の要素（['apple', 'ringo']）をCとして取り出す方法
#C = ['apple', 'ringo']

result = []
while C:
        for m in range(len(A)):
            if A[m][0] == C[0]:
                a = []
                a.append(A[m]) 
                a.append(C[1]) 

                 result.append(a) 
                #（疑問点２）Aの１番目の要素を読み込む式
```

上のような処理をして以下の結果を得たいと考えています。

```py
result = [['apple', 1, 'ringo'],['banana', 2, 'banana'],['orange', 3, 'orenji'],['grape', 4, 'budou']]
```

書き方が分からない箇所が２つ（疑問点１と疑問点２）あり、どのように書いたら良いか教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 参考までに、こんな方法もあります。`result = [[a, b, c] for (a, b), (_, c) in zip(A, B)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Q1. Bの０番目の要素（['apple', 'ringo']）をCとして取り出す方法

B[0]によってBの0番目の要素を取り出す事ができます。

```
>>> C = B[0]
```

しかし文意を見る限り、欲しいのは0番目の要素だけではなくBの要素を順に処理したいように見えます（ですよね？）。それなら素直にfor文を使った方がいいでしょう。

#### Q2. Aの１番目の要素を読み込む式

本当に必要なのはAの要素(D)の中の1番目の要素。

```
result = []
for C in B:
    # 同様にAのループもfor文で取り出す。
    # DはAの要素のひとつ。
    for D in A:
        if D[0] == C[0]:
            a = []
            a.append(C[0])
            a.append(D[1])
            a.append(C[1])
            result.append(a)

print(result)
```

`while` を使ってもできなくは無いけど、操作が破壊的になるから素直にfor使っとくのがいいと思うよ。

```
result_while = []

tmp_b = B.copy()
while tmp_b:
    C = tmp_b.pop(0)  # tmp_bの最初の要素を削る

    tmp_a = A.copy()
    while tmp_a:
        D = tmp_a.pop(0)

        if D[0] == C[0]:
            a = []
            a.append(C[0])
            a.append(D[1])
            a.append(C[1])
            result_while.append(a)

print(result_while)
```

効果的にやるなら、まずAを辞書にしておくかな。

```
idx_of = {x[0]: x[1] for x in A}  # idx_of['apple'] で1が取れるようになる。
```

そうすればif文も要らない。

```
result_dict = []
for C in B:
    result_dict.append([C[0], idx_of[C[0]], C[1]])

print(result_dict)
```

これぐらい短くなれば内包表記のメリットが生きてくる。

```
result_lc = [[x[0], idx_of[x[0]], x[1]] for x in B]
print(result_lc)
```